# lmfit - SineModel+ConstantModel appears inaccurate fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm trying to fit a simple sine function to some experimental data using lmfit and I find that the SineModel with a constant model offset returns, what looks like an inaccurate fit to the data (to me). I suppose it may be helpful to highlight that I am most interested in the frequency of the peaks (and I appreciate that I can simply use a scipy.find_peaks() but would prefer to show a fit to the data).

I use the function below for lmfit model:

```
def Sine(self, x_axis, y_axis):
    sine = SineModel()
    const = ConstantModel()

    x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_axis), max(x_axis), x_axis.size)
    guess_sine = sine.guess(y_axis, x=x_fit)

    pars = sine.guess(y_axis, x=x_fit)
    sine_offset = SineModel() + ConstantModel()

    pars.add('c', value=1, vary=True)

    result = sine_offset.fit(y_axis, pars, x=x_fit)

   return result
```

Sine function output (graph and report results) are provided here:
[SineModel+ConstModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvLFq.png)

I then tried to define my own function, defining my own parameters and evaluating in the same lmfit method, providing sensible "guess" initial values etc.

```
def Sine_User2(self, x_axis, y_axis):
   def sine_func(x, amplitude, freq, shift, c):
        return amplitude * np.sin(freq * x + shift) + c

    sinemodel = Model(sine_func)

    # Take a FFT of the data to provide a guess starting location for the curve fitting
    x = np.array(x_axis)
    y = np.array(y_axis)
    ff = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), (x[1] - x[0]))   # assume uniform spacing
    Fyy = abs(np.fft.fft(y))
    guess_freq = abs(ff[np.argmax(Fyy[1:]) + 1]) * 2. * np.pi
    guess_amp = np.std(y) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = np.mean(y)

    x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_axis), max(x_axis), x_axis.size)

    params = sinemodel.make_params(amplitude = guess_amp, freq = guess_freq, shift = 0, c = guess_offset )
    result = sinemodel.fit(y_axis, params, x = x_fit)

    return result
```

The output of the user defined model appears to provide a much closer fit to the data, however, the report does not provide uncertainties citing a warning that the "Uncertainties could not be estimated":

SineUser2 function outputs (graph and report results) are provided here: [User Defined Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZe7l.png)

I then tried to include min/max values to the parameters by replacing the "sinmodel.make_params" line with:

```
    params = Parameters()
    params.add('amplitude', value=guess_amp, min = 0)
    params.add('freq', value=guess_freq, min=0)
    params.add('shift', value=0, min=-2*np.pi, max=2*np.pi)
    params.add('c', value=guess_offset)
```

But the results resort back to the SineModel+ConstModel results seen in the first linked graph/report results. Therefore it must be something to do with the way I'm setting initial values.

The fit using the "SineUser2" function appears to be better. Is there a way to improve the fit for "Sine" function in the first block of code.

Why are the uncertainties not calculated in the second function "Sine_User2"?

Data (.csv):

```
Wavelength (nm),Power (dBm),,,,,
1549.9,-13.76008731,,,,,
1549.905,-13.69423162,,,,,
1549.91,-12.59004339,,,,,
1549.915,-11.31061848,,,,,
1549.92,-10.58731809,,,,,
1549.925,-10.19024329,,,,,
1549.93,-10.07301418,,,,,
1549.935,-10.19513172,,,,,
1549.94,-10.45582159,,,,,
1549.945,-11.15984161,,,,,
1549.95,-12.15876596,,,,,
1549.955,-13.44674933,,,,,
1549.96,-13.56388277,,,,,
1549.965,-12.2513065,,,,,
1549.97,-11.08699015,,,,,
1549.975,-10.43829185,,,,,
1549.98,-10.12861158,,,,,
1549.985,-10.0962929,,,,,
1549.99,-10.1852173,,,,,
1549.995,-10.55438183,,,,,
1550,-11.19555345,,,,,
1550.005,-12.28715299,,,,,
1550.01,-13.5153863,,,,,
1550.015,-13.47019261,,,,,
1550.02,-12.12394732,,,,,
1550.025,-11.01946751,,,,,
1550.03,-10.42138778,,,,,
1550.035,-10.14438079,,,,,
1550.04,-10.05681218,,,,,
1550.045,-10.17148605,,,,,
1550.05,-10.56046759,,,,,
1550.055,-11.11621478,,,,,
1550.06,-12.19930263,,,,,
1550.065,-13.48428349,,,,,
1550.07,-13.43424913,,,,,
1550.075,-12.08019952,,,,,
1550.08,-11.08731704,,,,,
1550.085,-10.45730899,,,,,
1550.09,-10.11278169,,,,,
1550.095,-10.00651194,,,,,
,,,,,,
```

Comment: 1. Providing a complete, minimal example is always helpful.  I   2. What makes you conclude that the fit is not good? You get the result but did not show the results. You hint that something in the report did not make sense, but don't show what that is... why are you asking for help and withholding this information?  3. Guessing the frequency with an FFT definitely makes sense, but are you saying that the initial parameter values give a better fit than the fit?   I don't understand (at all!) what your "example 2" is.

Comment: The full result report and plotted graphs are available in the image links. Example 1 refers to the first function used "SineModel + ConstModel" and example 2 is the User Defined function.

Comment: Without your data (numerical) one cannot reproduce what you did and look where is the trouble.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response - I have now included numerical data and I have tried to make my question easier to follow.